# Cannot connect to LocalIP or Localhost (127.0.0.1) Using Arduino ESP8266 or Compatible Boards

Tags: tcp, arduino, esp8266, loopback-address

I am trying to connect my Arduino ESP8266 or any of the compatible boards like WeMos mini or NodeMCU to my local server, either `localhost(127.0.0.1)` or `172.xx.xx.xxx port 80`.

I get an `httpResponseCode` -1 error. But if I have it connected to a remote server I get an `httpResponseCode 200 (OK)`.

I am running an `XMPP` server (even tested with Coldfusion server). My code is as below. Can anybody help?

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";

//Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
String serverName = "http://stackoverflow.com";// returns 200 (ok results)
//String serverName = "127.0.0.1"; // Gives -1 error, Tried IP addresses with 172.xx.xx.xx or even 192.168.xx.xx.

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
// Timer set to 10 minutes (600000)
// unsigned long timerDelay = 600000;
// Set timer to 5 seconds (5000)
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 10 minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED){
      HTTPClient http;
      String serverPath = serverName + "?temperature=24.37";
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      //http.begin(serverPath.c_str());
        http.begin(serverName);
      // Send HTTP GET request
        int httpResponseCode = http.GET();
      
        if (httpResponseCode>0) {
          Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
          String payload = http.getString();
          Serial.println(payload);
        } else {
          Serial.print("Error code: ");
          Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      }
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    } else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address 127.0.0.1 is *the Arduino itself*, not your local server.

Every host/computer with an IP address also has an IP address 127.0.0.1; it is the address of the *loopback interface*.

This *localhost* address always refers to the *current computer*. The Arduino also has this address, and you are trying to connect to it.

Use the IP address of your XMPP server; find out what the address is first, that works much better than guessing and trying.

Comment: The IP Address of my Arduino is 192.168.10.15 and not 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is localhost and XAMPP runs on it